# Android overriding onClick(View v) - is there a good solution to use for all buttons in an application

Tags: android, onclick, android-button, onclicklistener

As you know we can override a few methods for each type of View that we have created. I am not doing any xml layout code because a lot of stuff changes form at runtime and there are things that are created dynamically so the programmatic solution is the best route for me here.

So to get to the gist of my issue lets say that i have 50 buttons in my Android App. These buttons could potentially be on one Activity but more than likely could span out across multiple screens(Activites).

I have created a button class called CustomButton that overrides the onClick(View view) method. What if some of the buttons are supposed to do some action(lets say they are a part of a linearlayout) and some are part of something like a relative layout and in each relative layout you want to get information about the relative layout that this button resides in(perhaps you what to get information about all the textviews in the same relative layout, etc etc).

One solution of course is that you could get the ID of each button and do a switch(case) or something and depending on what the ID of the button that is returned you can do something. The problem is is i have 50 buttons. What if i had 200? Should i really have to do 200 case checks in my switch statement to figure out what action i need to take?

So i am trying to figure out what information is available to me that i am not aware of that I could use when override the onClick.

```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(!getClickInfo()){
        ((CustomButton)v).setText("I clicked the button");
        setClickInfo(true);
    }
    else{
        isClicked = false;
        ((CustomButton)v).setText("This is the button that i want to click");


    }

}
```

so here is an example. I have passed in the View that represents the button that was clicked and i can change the text of the button as i click on it over and over again. But what if the Button was part of a relative layout? Can i get any other information about other views that also are a part of the same relative layout? What if some buttons i wanted to change the background color of each time i clicked it instead of changing the text? If I have X number of buttons I am trying to stay away from creating X number of IDs -- as i pointed out you could potentially have hundreds of them.

Was wondering if anyone might have any ideas on what would be a better route here than having a potentially unlimited about of case checks inside a switch statement. If i could find out which view the button came from(in my case the button was part of an outer view) then i could do a switch on my views instead of just my buttons - and making my switch statement much less cumbersome and easier to maintain. thanks.

Comment: can you say exactly what you want to do in a few sentences? your explanation isn't clear!

Comment: I don't know if I understand what are you trying to do(especially the extra information you are trying to gather) but you could set a `tag` attribute on your `Button`(in the xml layout) representing a `String` and base on that `String` obtain more info about the `Button` context.

Comment: please look below to an answer to YuviDroid. sorry for the initial confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure as what your end goal is. But from your view (button) you can get its parent (e.g. a RelativeLayout). Then once you have your view group you can get its children and do whatever you need to.

For example:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ViewParent parent = v.getParent();
    if (parent instanceof RelativeLayout) {
        // your button is inside a RelativeLayout
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) parent;
        int numChildren = rl.getChildCount();
        // loop through children if you need to (use rl.getChildAt(index) to get each child)
        ...
    }
}
```

If you don't need to know if it's actually a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout, or whatever just use ViewGroup.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes i realized maybe i wasnt as clear as i wanted to be. Obviously this is the case since I got multiple answers wondering what i what talking about. In my case I have a linear layout of relative layouts. In each relative layout i have a button and some other views as well(textviews). when i click on any of these buttons i want to be able to get the value of the text one of the textviews that resides in the same relative layout. depending on which relative layout this button resides in, the value of the getText call is going to be different.

Comment: ..Continued - if i can do as you suggest above then i wont have to assign button ids for every button which is what i wanted to stay away from. In the case of the relative layouts as you suggested above i think by itself this will work out well. What if i had 5 linear layouts and in each linear layout i had 5 buttons in each. If i do the check to see if a button is an instance of a linear layout, in this case it isnt going to be enough information because each set of buttons in each linear layout is going to have a different sent of actions that i want to implement.

Comment: --Continued again. I could potentially get the name of the linearlayout to let me know what actions i might want to take but if i have something like ArrayList<LinearLayout> myLinearLayouts = new ArraysList<LinearLayout>(some number) - then i would have to either check array index and hardcode the check for this in a switch statement. Anyway just trying to find the most elegant, object oriented approach as possible. thanks for your input Yuvi.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you could simply have a few different CustomButton extensions: say `RelativeLayoutButton` and `LinearLayoutButton`, and have them implement OnClickListener. Override `onClick()` within the extended class, and handle the implementation per Button type.

You can access the entire View hierarchy if needed. Say, something like this:

```
//assuming a reference to Button button

//get a reference to the parent
View v = button.getParent();
ViewGroup parent;
ArrayList<View> siblings = new ArrayList<>();

if(v instanceof ViewGroup) parent = (ViewGroup) v;
for(int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
    siblings.add(parent.getChildAt(i));
}
```

Comment: I think you and Yuvi had the idea of what i wanted to do. please refer to my replies above. Once i find out what kind of  instance i am working with (instanceof RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, etc etc) it would nice to figure out the variable name of the layouts that i had initially assigned for each of them when building them..i.e. myLinearLayoutCars, myLinearLayoutAnimals, myRelativeLayoutA, myRelativeLayoutB and perhaps use a switch statement to check the different "kinds" of linear or relative layouts that i have. The reason for this is, as i so uneloquently tried to explain before...

Comment: is that different linearLayouts or relativeLayouts are going to have different views types of views(children) inside of them and a different amount. So depending on which "type" of layout that i have(check by layout variable name?) will depend on which type of view that i want to extract. In the case of RelativeLayoutA this particular type has an image view, 2 textviews and the button in question that i click of course. If i know that i clicked with the parent of RelativeLayoutA then somehow i would like to extract a particular textView(also by name?). Anyway i hope that wasnt too confusing...